# How to overcome the windows stopped working error message?

Tags: c

I'm writing a program for a simple calculator that accepts a string (without spaces) with two operators and one operand and outputs the result. My program compiles just fine but during runtime, I'm getting the windows stopped working error message. What could be the reason for it? I think it's good something to do with my program's logic. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    int operand_1 = 0, operand_2 = 0, i = 0, result = 0;
    char string[10], *ptr, operation;
    ptr = string;
    printf("Enter the expression:\n");
    gets(string);
    //puts(string);
    while(*ptr==0||*ptr==1||*ptr==2||*ptr==3||*ptr==4||*ptr==5||*ptr==6||*ptr==7||*ptr==8||*ptr==9)
    {
        operand_1 = operand_1 + ((int)*ptr)*pow(10,i);
        i++;
        ptr++;
    }
    operation = *ptr;
    ptr++;
    i=0;
    while(ptr!=NULL)
    {
        operand_2 = operand_2 + ((int)*ptr)*pow(10,i); 
        i++;
        ptr++;
    }
    switch(operation)
    {
        case '+':
            result = operand_1 + operand_2;
        case '-':
            result = operand_1 + operand_2;
        case '*':
            result = operand_1 * operand_2;
        case '/':
            result = operand_1 / operand_2;
        case '%':
            result = operand_1 % operand_2;
    }
    printf("%d",result);
}
```

Comment: Ps: I don't want to use any predefined functions :)

Comment: First of all - stop using `gets`. This function is dangerous and not a part of C anymore

Comment: Second, `ptr` is a pointer to `string`, yet you compare it to numbers.

Comment: Where you have `while(ptr!=NULL)` did you mean `while(*ptr!= 0)`?

Comment: "Stopped working" usually means it jammed up into an infinite loop. Find out by using a debugger where you get stuck. It's an essential skill. Remember "compiles fine" doesn't mean a thing about how correct your code is.

Comment: Note that `case` statements "fall through", so you *must* `break` between each or the end result is you'll run every single one for an operation like `+` at the top.

Comment: The character `'0'` is *significantly* different from the ASCII `0` character (NUL). Do not confuse the two.

Comment: Also instead of the `if (*ptr==0||*ptr==1||*ptr==2...)` just do `if (*ptr >= 0 && *ptr <= 9)` which is *way* more concise, though do keep in mind you probably mean `if (*ptr >= '0' && *ptr <= '9')`

Comment: The windows stopped working message means your program crashed. If you create an integer variable digit and compute it as `digit = *ptr - '0'`, things will be more clear. Even after you fix your crashes, I don't think your math is right.  if the user enters 10, you will save the first digit as 1 in operand_1.  Then the 2nd time through the loop, you'll raise the second digit 0 to the 1st power and add it to 1, which gives you only 1 and not 10.

Comment: Fixing a 'windows stopped working' message is trivial. Try Linux, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved the problem and also improved the logic of the program so that it works fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
while(1)
{
int operand_1 = 0, operand_2 = 0, i = 0, result = 0;
char string[10], *ptr, operation;
ptr = string;
printf("\nEnter the expression:");
scanf("%s",string);
if (*ptr=='q' || *ptr=='Q' && *(ptr+1)=='u' || *(ptr+1)=='U' && *(ptr+2)=='i' || *(ptr+2)=='I' && *(ptr+3)=='t' || *(ptr+3)=='T')
{
printf("\nBye");
break;
}
while(*ptr>='0' && *ptr<='9')
{
operand_1 = operand_1*10 + (*ptr - 48);
i++;
ptr++;
}
operation = *ptr;
ptr++;
i=0;
while(*ptr>='0' && *ptr<='9')
{
operand_2 = operand_2*10 + (*ptr-48);
i++;
ptr++;
}
if(operand_2 == 0)
{
printf("\nDivision by zero");
continue;
}
switch(operation)
{
case '+':
result = operand_1 + operand_2;
break;
case '-':
result = operand_1 - operand_2;
break;
case '*':
result = operand_1 * operand_2;
break;
case '/':
result = operand_1 / operand_2;
break;
case '%':
result = operand_1 % operand_2;
break;
}
printf("\nResult = %d",result);
}
}
```

Hope it helps someone in need :)

Comment: Thanks! It might be helpful to briefly explain what the problem was, and also to fix the indentation of your updated code.